# Configuration file for mobile web app

Tags: html, cordova, web-applications

I'm creating a web application in HTML5/Phonegap. I want to have a configuration file where I can specify the IP addresses of all servers I have to use in my app and also information about the user. How I should properly do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an application using PhoneGap Framework then you can configure your whole application using 2 ways.

1. Using the user interface of your PhoneGap account.Go to **settings** of your application
   in your PhoneGap account from where you can configure your application.
2. Using the `config.xml` file that is there in your application root folder.Here is the
   link for one Example:

   [config.xml](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml)